# Join two model and get records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On rails application I have user and requests model. The relation between is the following;

```
User
has_many :requests

Request
belongs_to :user
```

I have `@users` variable, which consist of some of the users (lets say first 10 users). I would like to get all the requests that are belongs to `@users`.

I have started with;

`@users.joins(:requests)` but returns the users. I would like to get all the requests of these users.
When I try;

```
Request.all.joins(:users).where(:requests => {user_id: @users.id})
```

gives error because `@users` not a single record.

Error:

```
Request.all.joins(:users).where(:requests => {user_id: @users.id}).all
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa573710bb8>
    from /Users/shalafi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/shalafi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
Request.where(user: @users)
```

Rails is clever that way. It's essentially doing this:

```
Request.where(user_id: @users.ids)
```

Which is essentially doing this:

```
Request.where(user_id: @users.map{|u| u.id})
```

Now, you *could* do all the joining yourself (as you started out doing). But, why do that to yourself?

Doesn't this:

```
Request.where(user: @users)
```

Make you feel like rainbows and cotton candy while this:

```
Request.all.joins(:users).where(:requests => {user_id: @users.map{|u|u.id}})
```

Makes you feel like spiders and worms?

Part of the syntactic sugar you get with your `belongs_to :user` declaration is that you can use the more streamlined version without having to bare knuckle it yourself.

Comment: Simplified version: `Request.joins(:users).where(requests: { user_id: @users }` (passing a scope to a `where` clause is OK because Rails guesses that you want their id attribute, and will nest the SQL query with a simple `user_id IN (SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE [...])`